# Strange message when sorting objects of a class

Tags: python, oop

if I run this programm in order to sort my list after the attribute "name", I only receive this:

```
[<__main__.Gericht object at 0x00000190D292FE50>, <__main__.Gericht object at 0x00000190D292FD90>, <__main__.Gericht object at 0x00000190D292FEB0>, <__main__.Gericht object at 0x00000190D292FDF0>]
```

Could you help me to get the real results?

```
class Gericht:

    def __init__(self, name, preis, calories, alergene = []):
        self.name = name
        self.preis = preis
        self.calories = calories
        self.alergene = alergene

def sortbyName(input):
    sort = sorted(input, key=lambda gericht: gericht.name)
    return sort

speisekarte = [Gericht("Spaghetti", 7.5, 750, [1, "a"]), Gericht("Brotstulle", 3, 250, []), Gericht("Tofu", 13, 634, [1, 2, 3, "b"]), Gericht("Eis", 1, 120, ["c", "d"]) ]

print(sortbyName(speisekarte))
```

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: For reference, try `print(Greicht(...))`, where `...` is some valid input

Comment: If you want a nice fancy string, look up how to implement `__str__` and/or `__repr__`

Comment: beware that `alergene = []`!  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument.  The easy fix is to make the default `None` and then say `self.alergene = alergene or []` in the body of the `__init__`.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535327/4046632

Answer (score 0):

Add something like:

```
    def __repr___(self) -> str:
        return "Some Gereicht object"
```

to your `Gereicht` class.  Modify to taste until you get the output you want from your printed list.