# Converting OOP objects to text in Python

Tags: python, oop

I am still noob at OOP.

```
class ItemPrices:
def __init__(self, name=" ", exval=0, chval=0, curtype= " "):
    self.name = name
    self.exaltedValue = exval
    self.chaosValue = chval
    self.currType = curtype
  def Incubator_Values(self):
    response_API = requests.get("https://poe.ninja/api/data/itemoverview?league=Scourge&type=Incubator")
    data = response_API.text
    os.chdir(
        r"C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\GithubPushs\psychescape_price_fetcher\psychescape_price_fetcher\values")
    parse_json = json.loads(data)
    with open("incubators.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(" ")
    j = 0
    for i in parse_json["lines"]:
        list = []
        if (i["chaosValue"] > chaos_ex_ratio):
            self.name = i["name"]
            self.exaltedValue = i["exaltedValue"]
            self.currType = "Exalted Orb"
            print(self.name)
            list.append(self)
            j = j + 1
            print("Current iteration> ", j)
        else:
            self.name = i["name"]
            self.exaltedValue = i["chaosValue"]
            self.currType = "Chaos Orb"
            print(self.name)
            list.append(self)
            j = j + 1
            print("Current iteration> ", j)
        os.chdir(
            r"C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\GithubPushs\psychescape_price_fetcher\psychescape_price_fetcher\values")
        with open("incubators.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(str(list))
            file.write("\n")
            file.close()
    print("Incubator values has now storaged at IncubatorValues class and imported to incubators.txt")
    print(self)
```

Above is an OOP loop I am trying to build. Class and self is working perfectly, but when I
append values to list and write it to "incubators.txt" it only writes values like:

```
[<__main__.ItemPrices object at 0x0000023A951ACFD0>]
[<__main__.ItemPrices object at 0x0000023A951ACFD0>]
[<__main__.ItemPrices object at 0x0000023A951ACFD0>]
[<__main__.ItemPrices object at 0x0000023A951ACFD0>]
[<__main__.ItemPrices object at 0x0000023A951ACFD0>]
```

When printing self.name, self.exaltedValue or self.chaosValue I can see that I manage to fetch strings and integers but can only write objects to the file. How can I also write that strs and ints to the file? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Yep second def was inappropiately intended sorry for that!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Comment: No sadly. Didnt work when I implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your list to JSON format and then write to the file.

Use this snippet :

```
result=json.dumps(list, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

Then, you can then write the result in the file