# representing a dataclass as a dictionary/JSON in python without calling a method

Tags: python, json, class, dictionary, python-dataclasses

I have, for example, this class:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Example:
    name: str = "Hello"
    size: int = 10
```

I want to be able to return a dictionary of this class without calling a to_dict function, **dict** or dataclasses.asdict each time I instantiate, like:

```
e = Example()
print(e)

{'name': 'Hello', 'size': 5}
```

What I have tried and did not work is ineriting from dict and callint dict.**init** inside Example's **init**, it seems to not recognize the name and size

Is there a nice solution to this?

Editing: my goal is that type(e) will be dict and not str, returning the **dict** from **init** is not possible, also, the keys and values should be obtained dynamically, and the values for name and size might change depending on the instantiations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Comment: @AlexisG No, maybe I was a little unclear, I have edited my question

Comment: @user17319990. `print` can't return a `dict` but the string representation of a `dict`. It's what my solution does.

Comment: @user17319990 Yes, the print was a bad example of mine, i just want to return a dict of the class when i instantiate it, i have read about  __new__ but i cant access the attributes from there.

Comment: @user17319990 If it's a bad example, why not [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71305181/edit) it out? changing the behavior of `print` is a *very* bad practice, and I don't know anyone that would recommend going down that route. The purpose of `print(e)` mutating the type of `e` is very doubtful thing. I would suggest spending time composing exactly the type of problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

python class can provide a specific method to create a string representation:

```
def __str__(self):
```

Same as toString() java method.

Answer (score 1):

Override `__str__` method:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Example:
    name: str = "Hello"
    size: int = 10

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)

e = Example()
print(e)  # Use __str__ method
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Hello', 'size': 10}
```

Comment: Thank you!, but i meant that the the type of e will be dict and not Example. Kind of returning a the __dict__ from the __init__ even that its not possible to return a value from __init__

Comment: @user17319990 I think you need to spend a good amount of time figuring out exactly what *kind* of question you want to ask. Ensuring that `e` is type dict instead of Example is very confusing, and not likely to be possibly without calling a method like `asdict`. What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? As in, what is your use case? The `str()` method can convert to a string that looks like a dict, but if you want a dict to begin with, just use `e = {...}` and no need to bother with a dataclass at all.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution by using `__new__`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Example:
    name: str
    size: int

    def __init__(self, name, size):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return kwargs

e = Example(**{"name":"Hello", "size":10})
print(e)

>>>> out :
>>>> {'name': 'Hello', 'size': 10}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this as well, but
1. The keys are not obtained dynamicly, in this example this might be ok but in reality i have many big dataclasses 
2. If I need to create new instance of Example (like e2) with different values for name or size, I cant (from my understanding this is because the __new__ is called before the __init__)

Comment: I've edited my answer and tried to meet your criteria

Comment: Still a bit off, Example clas should be called like e = Example() and i dont want to create the __init__ and writing the name and size there by myself. Im starting to think that it might be impossible but thank you anyway!

Comment: Ho to you initialize the values in your dataclasses ?

Comment: Example() for {'name': 'Hello', 'size': 10}, Example(size=12) for {'name': 'Hello', 'size': 12}. The values for name and size might change, but they can still remain Hello and 10 if I do not set otherwise. The class itself looks like it is shown in the question itself. Is that what you meant in your question?

Comment: i'm confused because creating an `__init__` defeats the whole purpose of using a `@dataclass`. Add on `__new__` and maybe a `repr=False` and it's at this point you realize that the entire purpose of dataclasses is completely missed.