# calling a variable in init gives location of the variable instead of the value

Tags: python-3.x, stack

When I try to print the value of the self.store_obj_stack, it is giving me the location of that variable instead of the value.

```
class StackStorage(object):
def __init__(self, dataList):
self.dList = dataList
self.store_obj_stack = Stack()
print(self.store_obj_stack)
```

I have imported the Stack from the other class, which is like this:

```
from collections import deque
import copy

class Stack(object):
def __init__(self):
self.__stack = deque()
```

I am getting this:

<stack.Stack object at 0x1032fc580>

Comment: You need to define a `__str__()` method in the `Stack` class in order for it to print values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `__repr__()` if you want something back from Python.

For example, you could do

```
def __repr__(self):
    return whatever you want
```

Then you could do `print(something)`.

For more information, visit https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-repr-method-in-python