# How to print list of all class instances with their values instead of location in memory?

Tags: python, oop, return

I met that problem before while studying the OOP and lack experience for sure. Surfed through a lot of stackoverflow pages but somehow all suggestions do not help. Please, refer me to the appropriate resources or give some hint if possible. Thanks in advance!

```
 class Student:

    students = []

    def __init__(self, name, money):
        self.name = name
        self.money = money
        self.students.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def mostMoney(cls):
        all_money = [elt.money for elt in cls.students]

        if all(element == all_money[0] for element in all_money) == True:
            return cls.students
        else:
            for student in cls.students:
                max_money = student.money
                current_name = student.name
                if student.money >= max(all_money):
                    return max_money, current_name
                else:
                    continue


student_1 = Student('Stas', 800)
student_2 = Student('Yarik', 800)
student_3 = Student('Kris', 800)

print(Student.mostMoney())
```

**The idea to return all students if they have equal value in money.
Here is the return I get.**

```
[<__main__.Student object at 0x7f7ae679e130>, <__main__.Student object at 0x7f7ae66c2070>, <__main__.Student object at 0x7f7ae66c22e0>]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535327/3001761?

Comment: Implement `__repr__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga or `__str__`?

Comment: @MarkRansom well, that won't actually show up if the OP prints a list of Student instances or if the instance is in a built-in data structure, which defer to the object's `repr` instead of `str`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga true. I missed the part where they are printing a list and not a single object.

Comment: @MarkRansom yeah, and generally speaking, I would just implement `__repr__` because usually I just want that to be the same as `__str__` and `str(obj)` will defer to `obj.__repr__` if `obj.__str__` is not defined