# Printing complex object as multiline string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have very large settings for multiple applications and I want to print this as multi line string. Let me give example (simplified) and explain want I want to achieve and what I get. I think about use of some package to get such nice formatting.

I assume that constructors arguments are same to `__dict__` or `__slots__` - if not `__dict__` or `__slots__` is more important to show.

I wrote some formatting library for single line but maybe is better solution with multiline output and more options.

**Update** (important):

Please not suggest to customize __repr__ or __str__ - I can not or do not want to customize hundred of classes (especially from third party libraries).

```
class Endpoint:
    def __init__(self, host_or_ip: str, port: int):
        self.host_or_ip = host_or_ip
        self.port = port


class ConnectionSettings:
    def __init__(self, endpoints: list[Endpoint]):
        self.endpoints = endpoints


class FarmSettings:
    def __init__(self, name: str, connection_settings: ConnectionSettings):
        self.name = name
        self.connection_settings = connection_settings


def main():
    settings = FarmSettings(
        name='alfa',
        connection_settings=ConnectionSettings(
            endpoints=[
                Endpoint('localhost', 80)
            ]
        )
    )

    print(settings)
    
    # what I get from default __repr__
    #
    # <__main__.FarmSettings object at 0x00000203EF713AF0>
    #
    # what do I want from some method
    # FarmSettings(
    #     name='alfa',
    #     connection_settings=ConnectionSettings(
    #         endpoints=[
    #             Endpoint(name='localhost', port=80)
    #         ]
    #     )
    # )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You could just define a `__repr__` for your class to return that string and `print(settings)` will work the way you want. Making it a multiline string is trivial - Add a `\n` character wherever you want a newline

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Comment: This do not solve problem - I know how to write custom \_\_repr__ and \_\_str__. I do not want to write \_\_repr__ for hundred of classes (sometime you can not since classes are from third party libraries). It is not related to \_\_repr__ or \_\_str__ at all. Solution is need for any class without modification this class.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it is not such simple. It is also not duplicate. I am very skilled programmer with expert Python understanding (10 years or more).

Comment: You can't do what you want generically. To change the output in the manner you desire requires knowledge of the internals of the particular class being reformatted — and as you said you don't want to do this for large numbers of classes.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Not good idea to replace \_\_repr__ you can mess code - it can lead to bugs. Better is to traverse object tree to print result but it need to implement some code but cheaper than custom \_\_repr__.

Comment: @martineau That is true that there is no generic backward transformations to constructors but assume that it almost possible with some exceptions. See pprint it works for dict, list, set - same we can do here for object but with some exceptions. imprefect solutions are also good if no perfect solution.

Comment: Probably not relevant if your classes are already built, but I found that nice prints, esp on nesteds, were one benefit from using Pydantic classes.  Which do very well in configuration contexts .

Answer (score 3):

You could use e.g. `__dict__` to recursively transform your objects to a dictionary, and then use `pprint.pprint` or `json.dumps` to pretty-print this dictionary:

```
def dictify(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, (int, float, str, bool)):
        return obj
    if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        return list(map(dictify, obj))
    return {"_type": type(obj).__name__,
            **{k: dictify(v) for k, v in obj.__dict__.items()}}
    

settings = FarmSettings(
    name='alfa',
    connection_settings=ConnectionSettings(
        endpoints=[
            Endpoint('localhost', 80)
        ]
    )
)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(dictify(settings))
```

Sample output:

```
{'_type': 'FarmSettings',
 'connection_settings': {'_type': 'ConnectionSettings',
                         'endpoints': [{'_type': 'Endpoint',
                                        'host_or_ip': 'localhost',
                                        'port': 80}]},
 'name': 'alfa'}
```

Note: The shown function is rudimentary at best. It does not cover many cases of attribute values (e.g. `dict`, let alone any kinds of more exotic classes), and it also does not handle cyclic references in your model (i.e. it will run into endless recursion in that case).

Comment: I looks like the best solution (it not need to be perfect). I try to implement like this. If not better solution I will accept. I do similar solution for serialization of Python object with msgpack :) Simple and look great.

Comment: You can have also some \_\_slots__ but it not need to show this in examples whatever worth to remember when it need to be implemented :)

Comment: Upvoted but I’d also expect hassles around properties.

Comment: I create encoder which transform into YAML, Pretty format.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `__str__` (or `__repr__`) method to your class will allow you to overwrite the output of `print(<insert complex object here>)`. For example:

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.<attribute> + ...
```

So, for example, if you had a class like this:

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

print(Person("Ryan"))
```

You get the output:

```
Ryan
```

Comment: This do not solve problem - I know how to write custom \_\_repr__ and \_\_str__. I do not want to write \_\_repr__ for hundred of classes (sometime you can not since classes are from third party libraries). It is not related to \_\_repr__ or \_\_str__ at all. Solution is need for any class without modification this class.