# How to make a list inside a class static for the entire program

Tags: python

I'm messing around with classes and data flow and I am having difficulties creating a list of classes inside the class (to give control of the list to the class in itself).

```
class Person:

    listOfPeople = []

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.listOfPeople = []
        

    def set_age(self, age):
        if age <= 0:
            raise ValueError('The age must be positive')
        self._age = age

    def get_age(self):
        return self._age
    
    def AppendList(self):
        self.listOfPeople.append(self)

    def returnList(self):
        return self.listOfPeople

    age = property(fget=get_age, fset=set_age)



john = Person('John', 18)

barry = Person("Barry", 19)

john.AppendList()

barry.AppendList()


print(Person.listOfPeople)
```

The output is simply

> []

Let´s use this example. I want the class Person to have a list of people. That list of people has instances of the class it's in. I want the entire program to have access to this class, regardless of having an instance initialised. Is it even possible to do what I want in Python?

My expected output is a list with the 2 instances I added to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code automatically adds new instances to `Person.listOfPeople`

```
class Person:

listOfPeople = []

def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    Person.listOfPeople.append(self)
    

def set_age(self, age):
    if age <= 0:
        raise ValueError('The age must be positive')
    self._age = age

def get_age(self):
    return self._age

def AppendList(self):
    self.listOfPeople.append(self)

def returnList(self):
    return self.listOfPeople

def __repr__(self):             #I've added __repr__
    return self.name+' '+str(self.age)

age = property(fget=get_age, fset=set_age)



john = Person('John', 18)

barry = Person("Barry", 19)

# john.AppendList()

# barry.AppendList()


print(Person.listOfPeople)
```

the output: `[John 18, Barry 19]`
is this what you need?

Comment: This solution is good enough for show but if I later wanna use the list to access an instance, is it possible?

Comment: yes, you can iterate it and do with instances whatever you want to

Comment: this is typical one for the purpose of storing instances initiated from some class inside that some class

Comment: Is it possible to attribute a list to that list outside of the class? Something like `Person.listOfPeople = anotherList` ??

Comment: yes, but in reverse way. like: `anotherList = Person.listOfPeople` here `anotherList` is variable (=reference) to object `Person.listOfPeople`, but if you need to 'fix' it (= to create new object) you've to use `copy.deepcopy()`.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that imagine I want to store this list in a database but when I restart the application, the list is refilled with the data from the database. Is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248697/discussion-between-dmitriy-neledva-and-citrusboy).

Answer (score 2):

Okay so you need to create the list outside the definitions first.

Then you need to change the append function to this instead, `self.listOfPeople.append(self)` so that the variables are added into the list when you run it your way and remove the `self.listOfPeople` from the `__init__`.

Now the `listOfPeople` you initialized is shared between all instances.

```
class Person:
    listOfPeople = []

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        

    def set_age(self, age):
        if age <= 0:
            raise ValueError('The age must be positive')
        self._age = age

    def get_age(self):
        return self._age
    
    def AppendList(self):
        self.listOfPeople.append(self)

    def returnList(self):
        return self.listOfPeople

    age = property(fget=get_age, fset=set_age)


john = Person('John', 18)

barry = Person("Barry", 19)

john.AppendList()

barry.AppendList()

print(Person.listOfPeople)

for i in Person.listOfPeople:
    print (i.name, i.age)
```

Output for first part is:

```
[<__main__.Person object at 0x7fcb72395150>, <__main__.Person object at 0x7fcb723954d0>]
```

Output for the second part is:

```
John 18
Barry 19
```

Comment: In this case, the output is

[<__main__.Person object at 0x000002555A543FA0>, <__main__.Person object at 0x000002555A543E50>]

Comment: @CitrusBoy, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535327/4046632 It's another matter if it is good idea for an instance of a `Person` class to know about all other instances and yet another why you need the`AppendList()` method, when you can append to list in the `__init__`

Comment: @CitrusBoy I fixed it I will add the explanation now, is this what you wanted?

Comment: This solution doesn't append the class, just its properties, which makes it impossible to iterate with a for to manipulate the data.

Comment: @anarchy I'm curious how it works, `AppendList` method appends to `self`'s namespase only, so `class Person`'s namespace seems to be untouched, but in the end printing `print(Person.listOfPeople)` retruns  `[['John', 18], ['Barry', 19]]`. how does that works?

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva you are only creating 1 list which is shared

Comment: @CitrusBoy i understand what you want now, take a look at my code, it works exactly as you want.

Comment: @anarchy oh, i get it, there is no `listOfPeople` attribute in an instance namespace, so when we use it like `self.listOfPeople.append('something')` tree search finds `listOfPeople` inside class namespace and  `self.listOfPeople` actually turns into `Person.listOfPeople` and any further manipulations with it are applied to class attribute not to instance one.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of this

```
self.listOfPeople = []
```

This line overrides the class attribute and creates an instance attribute with the same name - not what you want.

Comment: That way, the output is [<__main__.Person object at 0x0000028928F23FA0>, <__main__.Person object at 0x0000028928F23E50>]

Comment: @CitrusBoy: yes, isn't that what you want?

Comment: @CitrusBoy yes, which is a list with the two person objects you created. You might want to clarify what output you are expecting.