# How to print my class and not get memory reference

Tags: python, class, methods, printing

I have a class called `Pension`, with attributes like a person's name, age, savings and a growth rate.

I have a class method which calculates the person's total savings at retirement year.

Under my main function, I want to print the class to see if my code is working as intended, but I don't know how to do as I only get the memory reference when printing.

How can I print the class instance, so that it goes through all its attributes and runs the function result, and prints the result? Worth to note; to run the function 'result' which calculates the total pension, the growth rate is user inputted and in a function of its own (and is run in main())

For example, if I try to print the 2nd last line: `print(pensions)` I only get the memory reference. So in this case, if a person (the data for which I read in from a file) has saved up 1000 dollars (using my result method), I would like that fact to be printed into a list.

This is my code:

```py
class Pension:
    def __init__(self, name,age,savings,growth):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.savings = savings
        self.growth = growth



    def result(self):
        amount=self.savings
        rate=1+(self.growth/100)
        years=65-self.age
        return (amount * (1 - pow(rate, years))) / (1 - rate)
        

def convert(elem: str):
    if not elem.isdigit():
        return elem
    return float(elem)


def convert_row(r: list) -> list:
   return [convert(e) for e in r]

def get_growth(msg: str = "Enter growth rate: "):
    return float((input(msg).strip()))


def main():
    with open('personer.txt') as f:
        raw_data = f.readlines()

    data = [row.split("/") for row in raw_data]
    data = [convert_row(row) for row in data]

    pensions = [Pension(*i, get_growth()) for i in data]
    

main()
```

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of the output you would like to see from `print(pensions)`.

Comment: You need to override the \_\_str__ dunder method

Comment: You want to print *instances* of the class. More specifically, you want something other than the default string representation provided by `object` for each instance. That's what the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods are for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `Pension` class object's perspective it doesn't actually matter how is the growth provided. Also in this case maybe it's worth to make the result a property, then there's no need to call it as a function (just access like any other property, but the values will be calculated "dynamically").
You can customize the `__str__` method to return any str representation of your object.

```
class Pension:
    def __init__(self, name,age,savings,growth):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.savings = savings
        self.growth = growth
        self._result = result

    @property
    def result(self):
        amount=self.savings
        rate=1+(self.growth/100)
        years=65-self.age
        return (amount * (1 - pow(rate, years))) / (1 - rate)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"Pension:\n{self.amount=}\n{self.age=}\n{self.savings}\n{self.growth=}\n{self.result}"
```

And then just:

```
for p in pensions:
    print(p)
```

Comment: Okay. The __str__ method helped clarify what I should do. Thanks alot.

What do you mean by making the result a property (practically speaking)? I googled what property is but I couldn't grasp it so quickly. Do you mean removing it as a method and solely having it under my init?

Comment: What I posted above should work (without changes). Here's a read about that:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-property-decorator/
Property is a decorator (in this case), which works as a getter (from C# or Java).
Use it like so: `p.result` to get (calculate) this value