# How can I recreate a class object for testing, tried debugging and printing relevant items but can't get it?

Tags: python, class

I have the following class:

```
class MessageContext:

    def __init__(self, raw_packet, packet_header, message_header, message_index):
        self.raw_packet = raw_packet
        self.pkthdr = packet_header
        self.msghdr = message_header
        self.msgidx = message_index
        self.msg_seqno = packet_header.seqno + message_index
```

And a function that creates objects using the above class:

```
def parsers(data): 
    ... 
    context = MessageContext(None, PacketAdapter(), msghdr, 0)
    self.on_message(rawmsg, context)
```

I am trying to recreate `context`, and when i set a `breakpoint` just after it and print `context`, I get:

```
<exchanges.protocols.blahblah.MessageContext object at 0x7337211520>
```

I have left out quite a bit of code as it is very long, but if any more information is needed I am happy to provide of course.

Here is what I get when I print the arguments of `MessageContext`:

print(PacketAdapter())   -> `<exchanges.blahblah.PacketAdapter object at 0x7f60929e1820>`

---

Following the comments below, the `PacketAdapter()` class looks like this:

```
class PacketAdapter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.seqno = 0
```

Comment: What you are seeing is objects which do not have a defined representation and fallback to the default. But anyway, what is `self` in `parsers` ? and what state is kept in `PacketAdapter` ? Please [edit] your question and make sure to include a [minimal reproducible
example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I can include `PacketAdapter` but it is the same as above. And I can include `self` of course. I am not sure in this instance what an 'example' would consist of! But let me add these to the question.

Comment: never mind, I think it's too difficult to reproduce, `self` is a dataset of a class, the class which the function `parser` above belongs to.

Comment: This is close to what I am after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print

Comment: Why is it not *exactly* what you are after?

Comment: I just want to have the string/int/whatever representation of the class variable, but I can't seem to print it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it is not what I am after because in my unit test, lets say I want to call on the function `self.on_message(rawmsg, context)` from my question above, I need to pass in a `context` argument into the function right?
But when I `print(context)` to see what this context argument looks, I get: <exchanges.protocols.ice.parser.PacketAdapter object at 0x7f60929e1820>

Comment: Then as the question you have linked shows, you have to implement the `__str__` or `__repr__` method of the `PacketAdapter` class. Or, what do you hope to get instead of `<exchanges.protocols.ice.parser.PacketAdapter object at 0x7f60929e1820>`?

Comment: Yes, but what do I put inside the `__str__` or `__repr__`? Let me add what the `PacketAfapter` class looks like at the moment. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You put whatever you want to get out.

Comment: OK, but I want to see what is being passed in at the moment. I am debugging it. The issue is that I didn't write this code, I am simply running a long chain of functions, one of which called on the `PacketAdapter` class above. And I need to replicate this in a unit test.

Comment: Ohhh is `self.seqno` what we are getting?