# Create a Custom Type Object that Mimics Core Type Behavior

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to create a custom type object that mimics the behavior of core types. EG. A variable type that is directly referenced, but has methods underneath it called by variable.method().

For Example (Edited):

```
>>> a = [4, 5, 2, 1, 3]
>>> type(a)
    <class 'list'>
>>> print(a)
    [4, 5, 2, 1, 3]
>>> a.sort()
>>> print(a)
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I Want to (edited):

```
>>> field = MineField_Type()
>>> type(field)
    <class 'minefield'>
>>> field.show()
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> field.populate_field()
>>> field.show()
    [['x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x']]
>>> field.manipulating_function()
>>> ...
```

I have tried a few different approaches and could be content with my alternative. However, I want the maturity of a single, proper custom type with sub methods. As well as, I would like to know if Python is capable of this and where I can learn more.
How can I do this in Python?

My Attempt:

```
""" Output
 : python .\MinefieldObject.py
 : <__main__.MineField_Des object at 0x00000193A9046420>"""

class MineField_Des:
    def __init__(self):
        self.generate_field()
        
    def generate_field(self):
        self.field = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
        
        return self.field

if __name__ == "__main__":
    field = MineField_Des()
    print(field)
```

Comment: You can implement `__str__` to get what you describe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Comment: When returning a list:  TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Comment: I updated my example as it wasn't clear. I am not looking to print a string representation, but naturally assign the value. While allowing for sub methods to process the object structure, in an inheritance type of manner. EG. ObjType.method()

Comment: `def __str__(self): return str(self.field)` should work in your example.

Comment: Have you looked at the collections.abc module in the standard library?  Also the User* classes in the collections module.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I cannot use it as a str() type. I don't want "casting".

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what's going on with the built-in types. You've got some idea of what it would mean for an object to be "directly referenced", but lists aren't "directly referenced" any more than your own objects are. Lists print very differently from your objects, but that's because they implement custom string conversion logic, not because they're "directly referenced".

Comment: @user2357112 with print() and generally all displaying aside, how would I create a multi-dimensional list type object organically, with sub-methods underneath it? Inheritance or is it possible?

Comment: @TomSmith: Generally, you don't. It's a bad idea. Instances of `list` get to be lists because, well, being an instance of `list` is what it *means* to be a list. You *can* technically make your objects be lists by subclassing `list`, but doing that causes way too many problems and has very few actual benefits.

Comment: If you have some concrete benefit in mind that you think your objects would get by being lists, you can ask a question about that, and we can probably tell you a better way to go about it.

Comment: Everything is an object. `dir(list)` may break some magic around `builtins`. Reproducing those double underscore methods (e.g. `__contains__`, `__str__`, `__getitem__` etc) in another class would make it mimic `list` well enough. Btw, why don't just inherit `list`? `Class MineField_Des(list)` and override what is necessary?

Comment: @user2357112 I rained it in on time consumption and continued my development. I have learned more about the specific application and intuition I desire. When I get more time I will post a new question with better description. Then just answer both questions. Thank you.

Comment: @Dmitry Perhaps that is my ultimate resolve. I may be putting "liquid paper on a bee" and calling it rocket science. But, I have flight in my plans. How I achieve it is the question. I have learned about my ultimate goal though. I thank you.